# Popup with ScrollPane makes main Stage TextField unresponsive to key events like LEFT, RIGHT, HOME, END

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2

I want to create a Popup for main Stage TextField. Popup contains ScrollPane which holds possible options as Buttons.
After Popup shown TextField key events like *left*, *rigth*, *home*, *end* have no effect. Key events are received on TextField.
Is there any reasonable solution or workaround for this issue.
To reproduce please type in some text and try to press left arrow.

```java
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
    import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
    import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
    import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
    import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
    import javafx.stage.Popup;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class PopupApp extends Application {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }

        @Override
        public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
            TextField textField = new TextField();
            StackPane stackPane = new StackPane(textField);

            stage.setScene(new Scene(stackPane));
            stage.show();

            ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(new VBox(new Button("Option1"), new Button("Option2")));
            Popup popup = new Popup();
            popup.getContent().add(scrollPane);

            Point2D pinPoint = textField.localToScreen(0., textField.getHeight());
            popup.show(textField, pinPoint.getX(), pinPoint.getY());

            textField.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, event -> {
                System.out.println("KEY_RELEASED " + event);
            });

            textField.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event -> {
                System.out.println("KEY_PRESSED " + event);
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can just use controlsfx and AutoCompletionBinding: Make a `List<String> yourList` with your options and bind them to your TextField `AutoCompletionBinding autoCompletionBinding = TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(yourTextField, yourList);` Do handle the action after you clicked on a option `autoCompletionBinding.setOnAutoCompleted(e->{your code});`

Comment: Reclaiming focus on the node that handles the key events may do the trick.

Comment: @micpog90 TextFields.bindAutoCompletion() is a part of ControlsFX library. Even if I would decide to use the library it does not solve my problem because my popup component is far more complicated than simple list.

Comment: @Sedrick Already tried. Wouldn't like to get into the details but does not solve the problem.

Comment: there's an [open regression](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8209788) which might be related: in that case, for an editable combobox, it was possible to tweak the inputMap of the listView in the dropdown .. btw, I see the eating of the left/right pressed even without scrollPane, happens for any pane

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the `KEY_PRESSED` event is not being received by your `textField` when pressing Keys like `Left, Right, ..`. This is shown by the output from your program.

You are facing this problem because `Events` are being redirected to `Popup`. If these events are consumed while dispatching, then the effect of these events are not shown by `textField`. In your case it is due to the presence of `Button` on `Popup`. (Most likely due to the presence of node that can receive focus. Not sure though). To solve this you can set your own `EventDispatcher`. Something like this before `popup.show()`:

```
 popup.setEventDispatcher((event, tail) -> {
        if (event.getEventType() != RedirectedEvent.REDIRECTED) {
            tail.dispatchEvent(event);
        }
        return null;
    });
```

All the redirected events into the Popup will now be discarded and further dispatching does not occur. You can tweak this to suit your requirement.

Comment: @kleopatra Please set the `EventDispatcher` before calling `popup.show()`

Comment: okay, now it's working - thanks :) you might consider adding this detail to your answer (wouldn't have expected the popup's scene/window to be accessible before showing)

Comment: Actually you are right to expect that. After your comment it hit me that popup is not a `Node`. It is a `Window` and `popup.getScene().getWindow()` is redundant. I have edited my code.